# Tableau - Filter Dimension on Max Value of Measure

Tags: filter, max, tableau-api

I'm trying to calculate the MAX value of column D of value E which resets for every A Column. Later I just need to show the MAX row of A.

Raw data looks like this:
[image]

The desired view would be like this:
[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is an excellent example of a question which can/should be answered using LOD Calculations.

To start, find the maximum [Percentage] (Column E) per [Name] (Column B):

```
{Fixed [Name]: MAX(Percentage)}
```

Then insert that calculation, call it "Max Per Name", into another calculation which will only show the [Letter] (Column D) if the [Percentage] and the [Max Per Name] match:

```
IF [Percentage] = [Max Per Name] THEN [Letter] END
```

The result will be a dimension which shows the [Letter] which matches the largest [Percentage] and 'Null' when not matched.

From here, just filter out 'Null' - the result will be exactly as you desire. You will even be able to take [Percentage] off the view and still see an accurate [Letter].

> Please note that while LOD Calculations are extremely powerful, they require a little more work to maintain and operate. They are a little more complex than normal calculations. Please take some time and read through this [LOD Overview](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/calculations_calculatedfields_lod_overview.htm) document to further familiarize yourself with their use/limitations.

Comment: Any luck on getting this solved? If you've solved on your own, please post answer and give green check mark to yourself. This will help others in the future with similar questions.